# Net Core: Use a Tag Helper in a Custom Tag Helper that returns Html?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am trying to conduct this question except in .Net Core 2.

[Can I use a Tag Helper in a custom Tag Helper that returns html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010429/can-i-use-a-tag-helper-in-a-custom-tag-helper-that-returns-html)

"
I would like to use a tag helper within a tag helper. I looked around and couldn't find anyone else trying to do this, am I using a poor convention or am I missing documentation?

Ex. Tag Helper A outputs HTML that contains another tag helper."

How would I resolve the compilation error below?

```
[HtmlTargetElement("tag-name")]
public class RazorTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<a asp-action=\"Home\" ");
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to process the   tag helper from C#? Or to reprocess the output HTML with tag helpers?
"

**Tried this marked Solution from Taylor Mullen:**

```
var anchorTagHelper = new AnchorTagHelper
{
    Action = "Home",
};

var anchorOutput = new TagHelperOutput("a", new TagHelperAttributeList(), (useCachedResult, encoder) => new HtmlString());
var anchorContext = new TagHelperContext(
    new TagHelperAttributeList(new[] { new TagHelperAttribute("asp-action", new HtmlString("Home")) }),
    new Dictionary<object, object>(),
    Guid.NewGuid());
await anchorTagHelper.ProcessAsync(anchorContext, anchorOutput);
output.Content.SetHtmlContent(anchorOutput);
```

**Receiving Error Below**

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'HtmlString.HtmlString(string)'
```

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859988/asp-net-core-bootstrap-4-tabs-tag-helper/56860762#56860762). I have answered a similar question some days ago. Have a look and let me know if it works for ya, if not I'll help you out more.

Comment: can you write a more tangible answer for my question? if it works, I can send points, thank you, looking at your answer right now

Comment: The only reason I said that is because I'm currently on the train and have to get home. However if no onehas answered it till then, I'd be more than happy to help.

Comment: For the received error you're getting, I think it's because `HtmlString` class doesn't have a parameter-less constructor and you're constructing an object with parameter-less constructor (On declaring `anchorOutput`)

Comment: @Ammar, TagHelperOutput() constructor takes a delegate not HtmlString() instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now this is has been one of my favorite question on here. Thankfully I've dealt with tag helpers enough. Here is the code.

```
[HtmlTargetElement(ParentAnchorTag)]
public class ParentActionTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string ParentAnchorTag = "p-a";

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext viewContext { get; set; }

    private readonly IHtmlGenerator _htmlGenerator;

    public ParentActionTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator)
    {
        _htmlGenerator = htmlGenerator;
    }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";

        var anchorTagHelper = new AnchorTagHelper(_htmlGenerator)
        {
            Action = "Privacy",
            ViewContext = viewContext,

        };
        var anchorOutput = new TagHelperOutput("a", new TagHelperAttributeList(),
            (useCachedResult, encoder) =>  Task.Factory.StartNew<TagHelperContent>(
                 () => new DefaultTagHelperContent()));
        anchorOutput.Content.AppendHtml("Privacy Link");
        var anchorContext = new TagHelperContext(
            new TagHelperAttributeList(new[]
            {
                new TagHelperAttribute("asp-action", new HtmlString("Privacy"))
            }),
                new Dictionary<object, object>(),
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        anchorTagHelper.ProcessAsync(anchorContext, anchorOutput).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(anchorOutput);
    }
}
```

First, to generate the href attribute using the action name, you need action name, you need to provide ViewContext to the AnchorTagHelper(it will throw an error otherwise), you can't inject that as a dependency. Lines 6-8 explain that, you also need the IHtmlGenerator which you need to pass only the AnchroTagHelper constructor. Then you create the context TagHelperOutput and TagHelperContext needed to call the processAsync method on anchor tag helper you instantiated. (Note - I am using GetAwaiter().GetResult() because this method is not async in my case, you can totally put this code in the ProcessAsync overriden method). So I help this solves your problem. I have tested it and it works.

My cshtml file.
[image]
My output.

[image: This is the output]

Comment: this answer seems a lot longer than one provided from Taylor Mullen, can you give the direct tangible equivalent? var anchorTagHelper = new AnchorTagHelper
{
    Action = "Home",
};

var anchorOutput = new TagHelperOutput("a", new TagHelperAttributeList(), (useCachedResult, encoder) => new HtmlString());
var anchorContext = new TagHelperContext(
    new TagHelperAttributeList(new[] { new TagHelperAttribute("asp-action", new HtmlString("Home")) }),
    new Dictionary<object, object>(),

Comment: Would you please compare the code? Taylor Mullen only provided you with the Process method, which was at the time(.net core 1.1) simpler to do. I have provided you with the full explanation.

Comment: What is the difference between `TagHelperAttributeList` parameter and explicitly setting values on `AnchorTagHelper`?  You seem to set the same value twice?